# Array initialisation differences

Tags: arrays, swift

With Xcode 6.1.1, run `xcrun swift`, and then:

```
1> let a: [String] = []
a: [String] = 0 values

2> let b = Array<String>()
b: [String] = 0 values

3> let c = [String]()
c: [(String)] = 0 values
```

Why was `c` initialised to an array of 1-tuples?

Comment: It's just a notation. You're looking into the sausage factory so you see the sausage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a notation. You're looking into the sausage factory so you see the bits of sausage; that's the price of using the REPL. Ask yourself in what way a 1-tuple differs from its contents... It doesn't. It's still just an array of string:

```
  1> var c = [String]()
c: [(String)] = 0 values
  2> c.append("hello")
  3> c
$R0: [(String)] = 1 value {
  [0] = "hello"
}
```

So `[0] = "hello"`. No tuples here.

Comment: To further elaborate, as far as the language is concerned, a 1-tuple (`(String)`) and a single value (`String`) are indistinguishable.